# Return values from function is empty: Why?

Tags: ios, swift

In QueryHK class I run a HealthKit query for steps and corresponding date.  I would like to write those data to an NSArray and return it so that I can call the function in the ViewController.

- **Question**:  the code from ViewController returns nothing, and no error. Why is the return empty?

It seems to me that the query does not "write to the return".

**QueryHK.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class QueryHK: NSObject {

var steps = Double()
var date = NSDate()

func performHKQuery () -> (steps: Double, date: NSDate){

    let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager.sharedInstance
    let stepsSample = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
    let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: stepsSample,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 0,
        sortDescriptors: nil)
        {
            (sampleQuery, samples, error) in

            for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample]
            {

                self.steps  = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit)
                self.date  = sample.startDate

                println("Query HealthKit steps: \(self.steps)")
                println("Query HealthKit date: \(self.date)")

            }
    }
    healthKitManager.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
    return (steps, date)
}
}
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var query = QueryHK()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        printStepsAndDate()
    }


    func printStepsAndDate() {

    println(query.performHKQuery().date)
    println(query.performHKQuery().steps)

    }
}
```

Comment: Check if vc1 object is not nil. Also its better to move these common methods to a different class and create its object in vc1 and vc2 in turn calling the method

Comment: When I run ViewController1 which prints self.steps and self.dates they are not nil. Agree on separating the code into classes.  I just have a habit of doing it this way when I try out new methods.

Comment: Sorry you are right, they were empty, the date was just initialised with todays date NSDate()..   So why is the return empty? Clearly the query does not "write to the return", and the return just returns the initialised values.  How can I return the data from the query?

Comment: Question is updated based on feedback from @Arun-Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `HKSampleQuery` is processed asynchronously - it returns right away and does it's work in the background. So your method finishes executing right away instead of handling the response in the results handler block. You would need to update your method to take a completion block instead of returning values.

**QueryHK.swift:**

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

struct Sample {
    let step: Double
    let date: NSDate
}

class QueryHK: NSObject {

func performHKQuery(completion: (samples: [Sample]) -> Void) {

    let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager.sharedInstance
    let stepsSample = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
    let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: stepsSample,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 0,
        sortDescriptors: nil)
        {
            (sampleQuery, samples, error) in

            var processedSamples = [Sample]()
            for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample]
            {
                processedSamples.append(Sample(step: sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit), date: sample.startDate))

                println("Query HealthKit steps: \(processedSamples.last?.step)")
                println("Query HealthKit date: \(processedSamples.last?.date)")
            }
            // Call the completion handler with the results here
            completion(samples: processedSamples)
    }
    healthKitManager.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
}
}
```

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var query = QueryHK()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        printStepsAndDate()
    }


    func printStepsAndDate() {
        query.performHKQuery() { steps in
            println(steps)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code gives 2 errors for completion handler 1): '(@lvalue Double, @lvalue NSDate) -> $T5' is not identical to '(steps: Double, date: NSDate)'. error 2): use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: @karlml my bad. Add self, like this: `completion(self.steps, self.date)`

Comment: I still get the error: '(@lvalue Double, @lvalue NSDate) -> $T5' is not identical to '(steps: Double, date: NSDate) and in the ViewController  query.performHKQuery() function i get error:  '(($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> ($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3, (($T4, $T5) -> ($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> (($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> $T3) -> (($T4, ($T4, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3, (($T4, $T5) -> $T3, $T5) -> $T3) -> $T3' is not convertible to '(steps: Double, date: NSDate)'

Comment: @karlml Did you define the method exactly like this: `func performHKQuery(completion: (steps: Double, date: NSDate) -> Void)`? Note the `-> Void` at the end.

Comment: @karlml And you might have to actually call the completion block with parameter labels, like this: `completion(steps: self.steps, date: self.date)`

Comment: But the problem is, your solution gets me only half way there, because the result only records the last value of the iteration sample in samples.  I want all of the data recorded, not just the last value.. :-)  Any idea?  thank you !

Comment: @karlml Yes, check out my edited answer. I have removed the 2 instance variables and created an array instead. I also added a custom struct called `Sample` which contains the step and date for each sample. In the for loop I then insert this struct into the array which then gets returned via the callback.

Comment: hmm thank you, now the QueryHK console outputs: 
Query HealthKit steps: Optional(200.0)
Query HealthKit date: Optional(2014-12-26 12:44:00 +0000)
etc....
I need to get rid of the optional in order to make this data useful for graphing etc... 

The ViewController console output is: [HKscratchPad.Sample, HKscratchPad.Sample, HKscratchPad.Sample, HKscratchPad.Sample, HKscratchPad.Sample]....

Comment: @karlml Well that's slightly out of the scope of the original question. You seems quite new to swift, so I suggest reading Apple's Swift e-book, which is available free in the iTunes Books store. Optionals are a concept that can't be explained in one comment. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496